# I set any CORS setting but doesn't work in my ASP.NET Core 5 Web API

Tags: .net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I enable all of the enable CORS settings, but some of these methods of request don't still work like Delete, Put.

This is my code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        var appSettings = Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings");

        services.Configure<ApplicationSettingsModel>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddControllersWithViews(options => options.UseGeneralRoutePrefix(appSettings.GetValue<string>("apiRoutePrefix") ?? ""));

        services.AddMvc(o => { o.UseGeneralRoutePrefix("api/v{version:apiVersion}"); });
        services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
        {
            config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            config.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            config.ReportApiVersions = true;
        });
        services.AddOurAuthentication(Configuration);

        services.AddControllers(c => c.Conventions.Add(new ApiExplorerGroupPerVersionConvention()))
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
            {
                NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
            };
        });
        services.AddCors(app =>
        {
            app.AddPolicy("allowAll", a => a.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains());
        });

        if (_enableSwagger)
            services.AddOurSwagger();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        SwaggerMiddleware(app);
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCors("allowAll");

        app.UseApiResponseAndExceptionWrapper();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(builder => builder.MapControllers());
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the place of Cors code in your startup. Put this code to the top of ConfigureServices

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigins", builder =>
            {
                       builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));

           ........... 
            
        }
```

app.UseCors should be placed between app.UseRouting() and app.UseAuthorization()

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
   {
            .....

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigins");

            app.UseAuthentication();
           app.UseAuthorization();

            ....
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this.
I change my code to below:

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
var appSettings = Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings");

```
        services.Configure<ApplicationSettingsModel>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddControllersWithViews(options => options.UseGeneralRoutePrefix(appSettings.GetValue<string>("apiRoutePrefix") ?? ""));

        services.AddMvc(o => { o.UseGeneralRoutePrefix("api/v{version:apiVersion}"); });
        services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
        {
            config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            config.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            config.ReportApiVersions = true;
        });
        services.AddOurAuthentication(Configuration);


        services.AddControllers(c => c.Conventions.Add(new ApiExplorerGroupPerVersionConvention()))
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
            {
                NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
            };
        });
      
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("allowAll",
                builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(s => true)
                    .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(9))
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .Build());
        });

        if (_enableSwagger)
            services.AddOurSwagger();


    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        SwaggerMiddleware(app);
     //   app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseCors("allowAll");
        app.UseCorsMiddleware();
        // app.UseApiResponseAndExceptionWrapper();

        app.UseEndpoints(builder => builder.MapControllers());
    }
```

and this code:

```
 public class CorsMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate Next;
        public CorsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            Next = next;
        }
        public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            return BeginInvoke(context);
        }
        private Task BeginInvoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", new[] { "true" });
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new[] { "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Athorization, ActualUserOrImpersonatedUserSamAccount, IsImpersonatedUser" });
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", new[] { "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" });
            if (context.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Options.Method)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                return context.Response.WriteAsync("OK");
            }
            return Next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }

    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class CorsMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseCorsMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<CorsMiddleware>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Edited from comment suggestion, removed AllowCredentials I noticed OP didn't have that in his code.

Try this, instead of creating a policy, what if you did this:

```
app.UseCors(x => x
     .AllowAnyMethod()
     .AllowAnyHeader()
     .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)); // allow any origin
```

If this works, it's because you were creating a policy and maybe the policy is not applying. But the above should just work without a policy.

You also mention that only some verbs don't work - it's possible that a cors error is masking a 500 exception, the way to test that is, with a 500 (or other) exception, your code will actually get hit, so you can test that with a breakpoint and if your breakpoint gets hit, it's not CORS even though the browser is saying that.

But most likely you were creating a policy, and not applying the policy to the things that aren't working. THe code above is global.

Comment: No! You're allowing all origins with credentials, which amounts to jettisoning the whole Same-Origin Policy. What you're suggesting is very insecure.

Comment: @jub0bs I get that, but he's already used that logic in his code example, I just reformatted his own code to be global (I think at least!)

Comment: @jub0bs Good opportunity to ask you though, I do use this type of thing for a public facing mobile app, aside from fronting with an API gateway pattern like in Amazon, I'm not sure I'd have much choice?

Comment: i use  .WithMethods("GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS"), but doesn't work

Comment: @mosi98 .Withmethods is not going to do anything, because you are already specifying AllowAnyMethod.

Comment: @DanChase yes, I removed AllowAnyMethod

Comment: @mosi98 put it back, did you try making it global as I suggested to see if it's the policy application causing the issue?